# How to get water out of ears?

Tags: cleaning, water, health

I have looked and I cannot find an answer to this!
Is there a quick way I can get water out of my ears after being in the pool without earplugs? I will accept the safest, fastest, and most useful answer.

Comment: You can also use rubbing alcohol on a q-tip to help dry the inside of your ears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here are some tips for you to get water out of ears](https://authorityremedies.com/how-to-get-water-out-of-your-ear/). An easy way is to chew or yawn. If you want to use gravity, there should be some steps:

- Tilt your head sideways
- Hold the ear that the water got into parallel to the ground
- Place the palm of your hand against your ear
- Press it hard for a couple of seconds
- After that, remove your hand quickly.

The fluid will be dislodged by a temporary vacuum that has just formed.
Remove the water draining from the ear by a cotton ear bud very carefully.
Note: Do not insert the ear bud in the ear.

Comment: Tilting my head sideways always does the job

Comment: I'm sure how much you value your dignity, but when I was younger, I used to tilt my head and jump up and down which worked everytime...

Answer (score 8):

One of my lifeguarding buddies shared this one with me. Just turn your head sideways (so your ear is facing the ground) and jump up and down a couple times. Comes right out, and it works pretty quick, usually on the first jump or two.

Comment: If I have water in both ears, would this make the opposing ear worse?

Comment: That's a really good question @Carl. In my experience it hasn't, although I'd suggest doing it with gentle hops if that's the case. It doesn't take much force for the water to come right out

Comment: @Carl, it'll have no effect.  The water in your ears is already as far in as it will get.

Answer (score 2):

Use gravity.

Place your head flat upon a pillow or a towel with your head to one side. Within a few minutes, the water will drain out of its own accord. Then, turn your head to face in the other direction with your other ear down to drain that one.

It's that simple. It's safer that putting anything into your ear. It works.

Comment: Sorry, i was unclear. I sort of want a quick way.

Comment: @Adamawesome4 I understand. Yes, of course. Why would you want to try a way that took longer than you need? This might be the fastest way, after all. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Heat therapy or hot compress is yet another good answer if you want to know how to get water out of your ears. It opens the Eustachian tubes (where the water usually gets stored) and frees the fluid from the ears quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with swimmer's ear, which can lead to bacterial infection, use a mixture of one part vinegar and one part alchol (10ml vinegar, 10 ml alcohol).  Drop about 5 ml in the ear and allow it to drain out.  My daughter sometimes gets ear infections from playing in the bathtub or swimming.  This was suggested by our pediatrician.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but it works. Scoop with your hand some water and pour into the ear that is already flooded. Let it stay for a few seconds so as the new water connects with the existing water inside the ear. Then quickly tilt your head the opposite direction sideways, causing the water to flow out of your ear due to inertia.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue and triggered its solution myself that worked for my friends too.
Follow these steps:

1. Move your face 90 degree rightwards so that your chin is directly above your right shoulder.
2. Gently bend down so that air passes through your ear hole and throw the water out.

Repeat the above steps for your left ear. If you did not get it on first try, repeat it. The hidden advantage is that it brings back rhythm of breathe for asthma patients.

Answer (score -1):

A hair dryer should evaporate the water. Just point it at your ear at the warmest heat setting you can handle (which might not be very warm!!), and let the air blow into your ear for a few minutes.

Be careful that the sound of the hair dryer's motor, or just the wind rushing into your ear, is not too loud, because that could either leave you with a ringing ear or possibly even damage your eardrum.